# Prompt request to enable flash on browsers

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, flash, firefox, safari

I have a webpage that has an animated flash gallery on its homepage.

By default, google chrome/firefox/safari ... does not let this page enable the flash plugin, so the gallery doesn't show.

Not only this happens, but also there is no prompt from the webpage requesting the user to enable flash, and the gallery completely disappear when flash is not enabled, so there's not even an error message saying that you need to enable flash to see the gallery.

What do I need to do on the page so that it requests the user to enable flash? Something like button to enable and then request permission from a browser.

Here is the sample which asks this permission in a browser.

https://quickfire.gcontent.eu/aurora/default.aspx

Cheers!

Comment: the link you shared is inaccessible

Comment: maybe, because this is a link I found on casino website and casino website do not allow in every country to be active. I will try to find a similar page which shows flash enable request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will request to enable the flash player if its already installed otherwise, it will direct you to adobe page to download the flash player.

```
<a href="https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Click here to activate it</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should take the hint...Flash is dead...not supported...on its last legs.. covert your gaming/gambling website to html5>Canvas>SVG>scripting.

IE also has ActiveX filtering that blocks ActiveX controls from running on websites. see Tools ActiveX filtering.

The common design pattern for embedded plugins/ActiveX controls is to provide a fallback (link, image) nested INSIDE the parent object.

```
<object data="uri to flash resource" type="application/flash">
<param name="autoplay"/>
<embed src="uri to flash resource" type="application/flash"/>
<p class="noflash">Opps.... your browser does not support flash, or it is disabled or it is blocked by ActiveX filtering.</p>
</object>
```

For activeX filtering feature detection.. place a hidden div at the top of your document.... directly after the body.
eg.

```
<body>
    <div role="alert" id="AXon" style="display:none;color:lime;background:orange">ActiveX filtering for this site is turned on...</div>
```

and at the bottom of the document (so it executes when the onload event fires) the following script block.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            // Best Practice: First detect if ActiveX Filtering is enabled
            if(document.documentMode&&document.documentMode>8){
            if (typeof window.external.msActiveXFilteringEnabled == "unknown"
                    && window.external.msActiveXFilteringEnabled() == true) {
                document.getElementById('AXon').style.display = 'block';
                //document.write("ActiveX Filtering has hidden this content.");
            }
            else {
                // Either the browser isn’t IE, or ActiveX Filtering is not enabled in IE
                //document.write('<a style=\"text-decoration: none;\" href=\"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=124807\"><img alt=\"Get Microsoft Silverlight\" src=\"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181\"/><\/a>');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

But the only best answer is to put Flash out of its misery.

Comment: Thanks for your help, But maybe I was not able to explain well, Yes, I agree the flash is out, but the problem is there is the third party which only provide the thing with flash and I should add them into my page and can not do anything besides that.

Comment: You could use html5 to replace your Gallery flash application...flash is an application that runs in a browser. HTML is the markup language that is used to render content IN a browser. a site like templatemonster.com has ready made templates, or you could program your site yourself. Have a look at your compeditors websites. what are they using? If you are a one man band, you can either learn yourself (web programming) or hire a web programmer or agency to build/convert your site.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I can understand you are trying to help me, But I strongly believe, removing the problem and ignore it instead of finding correct solution for it is not a good solution, of cause we can rebuild everything with flash, but that is no solution for it, There is possibility to have flash element permission request via HTML code which I found the way and mentioned in here, therefore rebuild more than 350 games is not an easy solution. :( once again, thanks for your help and comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I make a flash button and embed to my page overlayer with HTML button, then the user clicks on button, it event fire the flash button event and then the browser will ask for permission to run the flash on a browser.

This is work if a flash has been already installed on the browser. If not it will show the only text and can not find any solution to make this process in a browser.